# PhpWord doesn't replace text

Tags: php, docx, phpword

I have a docx file and I need to replace some text. This is done inside codeigniter framework; here is the code:

```
$this->load->library('word');       
$template = $this->word->loadTemplate($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/doc/assets/doc3.docx');
$template->setValue('replacename', 'new');
$template->save($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/doc/assets/helloWorld.docx');
```

When I open the new file I still get "replacename" instad of "new". "replacename" is formatted with Verdana font, 9pt font size (no underline or bold). Why it doesn't work?
Removing ${ } from setValue function (and from doc file) it works

Comment: share what you get when you do `var_dump(setValue('replacename','new'));`

Comment: It means that your `setValue()` is not working. Can you share the this function also

Comment: public function setValue($search, $replace) {
        if(substr($search, 0, 2) !== '${' && substr($search, -1) !== '}') {
            $search = '${'.$search.'}';
        }
        
        if(!is_array($replace)) {
            $replace = utf8_encode($replace);
        }
        
        $this->_documentXML = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->_documentXML);
    }

Comment: better to edit this in you question

Comment: Ok done, sorry :) anyway this is the default function, I don't edit it

Comment: it looks fine. You have to debug this function by putting `var_dumps` after each line in this function and see what it returns.

Comment: what setValue function should return?

Comment: see what you get in `_documentXML` by echoing it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30761/discussion-between-ahmed-and-pindol)

Comment: I get all the text inside the doc file and there is also replacename (with ${})

Comment: ahan, put `echo $search; exit();` after the 1st `if` block and see if you are getting the true values for it. Same with `$replace`

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that when you add text to a word file, it sometimes creates extra tags in the underlying xml file. So (pseudo code) `${NAME}` can become `<tag1>${</tag1><tag2>NAME</tag2><tag3>}</tag3>`

Because of this, phpword can't find your needle.

I'm using a mac with microsoft word and i can just cut all the contents of the word file and paste them again.

Word will than recreate the underlying xml file in which ${NAME} is 1 tag instead of 3.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution in http://phpword.codeplex.com/workitem/57... the problem seems to be when word generates his own code.

for the solution, just rename extension your template to zip, check in a file named 'document.xml' into 'word' folder, and search your code value... it should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
    <w:body>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00AC49DC" w:rsidRDefault="00243DD6">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>${test1}</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00243DD6" w:rsidRDefault="00243DD6">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>${test2}</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00243DD6" w:rsidRDefault="00243DD6">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>${test3}</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00243DD6" w:rsidRDefault="00243DD6">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>${test4}</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00243DD6" w:rsidRDefault="00243DD6">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>${</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>test5}</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00243DD6" w:rsidSect="00C107D0">
            <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" w:code="1"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="907" w:right="907" w:bottom="907" w:left="907" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:cols w:space="720"/>
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="272"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add 2 function to the file "TemplateProcessor.php"

```
public  function setValueAdvanced($search_replace)
    {
        foreach ($this->tempDocumentHeaders as $index => $headerXML) {
            $this->tempDocumentHeaders[$index] = $this->setValueForPartAdvanced($this->tempDocumentHeaders[$index], $search_replace);
        }

        $this->tempDocumentMainPart = $this->setValueForPartAdvanced($this->tempDocumentMainPart, $search_replace);

        foreach ($this->tempDocumentFooters as $index => $headerXML) {
            $this->tempDocumentFooters[$index] = $this->setValueForPartAdvanced($this->tempDocumentFooters[$index], $search_replace);
        }
    }
protected  function setValueForPartAdvanced($documentPartXML, $search_replace)
    {
        $pattern = '/<w:t>(.*?)<\/w:t>/';
        $rplStringBeginOffcetsStack = array();
        $rplStringEndOffcetsStack = array();
        $rplCleanedStrings = array();
        $stringsToClean = array();
        preg_match_all($pattern, $documentPartXML, $words, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

        $bux_founded = false;
        $searching_started = false;
        foreach($words[1] as $key_of_words => $word)
        {
            $exploded_chars = str_split($word[0]);
            foreach($exploded_chars as $key_of_chars => $char)
            {
                if ($bux_founded)
                {
                    if ($searching_started)
                    {
                        if ($char == "}")
                        {
                            $bux_founded = false;
                            $searching_started = false;
                            array_push($rplStringEndOffcetsStack, ($word[1]+mb_strlen($word[0])+6));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ($char == "{")
                        {
                            $searching_started = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $bux_founded = false;
                            array_pop($rplStringBeginOffcetsStack);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($char == "$")
                    {
                        $bux_founded = true;
                        array_push($rplStringBeginOffcetsStack, $word[1]-5);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for($index=0; $index<count($rplStringEndOffcetsStack); $index++)
        {
            $string_to_clean = substr($documentPartXML, $rplStringBeginOffcetsStack[$index], ($rplStringEndOffcetsStack[$index]-$rplStringBeginOffcetsStack[$index]));
            array_push($stringsToClean, $string_to_clean);
            preg_match_all($pattern, $string_to_clean, $words_to_concat);
            $cleaned_string = implode("", $words_to_concat[1]);
            $cleaned_string = preg_replace('/[${}]+/', '', $cleaned_string);
            array_push($rplCleanedStrings, $cleaned_string);
        }
        for ($index=0; $index<count($rplCleanedStrings); $index++)
        {
            foreach($search_replace as $key_search => $replace)
            {
                if ($rplCleanedStrings[$index] == $key_search)
                {
                    $documentPartXML = str_replace($stringsToClean[$index], "<w:t>".$replace."</w:t>", $documentPartXML);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $documentPartXML;
    }
```

How to use:
Use an array as the only parameter of function "setValueAdvanced", where "key" - a word, that we want to replace, and "value" - phrase we want to paste instead.
Important:
Inside a MS Word file use "${word_to_replace}" to "mark" a word that we want to replace, but key of an array should be "word_to_replace", without "${}"

Example code:

```
require_once 'PhpWord/Autoloader.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;

define('CLI', (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? true : false);
define('EOL', CLI ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');
define('SCRIPT_FILENAME', basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '.php'));
define('IS_INDEX', SCRIPT_FILENAME == 'index');

Autoloader::register();
Settings::loadConfig();

$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('your_file_name.docx');
$search_replace_array = array(
    'msword_hello'=>'Hello', #inside a MS Word file ${msword_hello} will change to Hello
    'msword_world'=>'World' #${msword_world} will change to World
);
$templateProcessor->setValueAdvanced($search_replace_array);


$templateProcessor->saveAs('your_file_name_changed.docx');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use new Template class with new method setValue()

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00243DD6" w:rsidRDefault="00243DD6">
        <w:r>
            <w:t>{</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
        <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>test5}</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

New method can replace it setValue('test5', 'MyValue');

Download new class: https://github.com/Arisse/PHPWord_CloneRow

Answer (score 2):

here i try and working well,

setValue function does not work because it include the format of word after generate to web. so the text you might replace not found.

the solution is
just type your ${replaceKey} to notepad and copy it to your_template.docx
it working for me.

notepad make all word format not included to the template so the function setValue can found it as expected.

Hope it Helping you guys.

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
function replaceText($element, $variable, $value) {
$text_class = 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Text';
$table_class = 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Table';
foreach ($element as $e) {
    if (get_class($e) !== $text_class && method_exists($e, 'getElements')) {
        replaceText($e->getElements(), $variable, $value);
    } elseif (get_class($e) === $text_class && ($match_count = substr_count($e->getText(), $variable))) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $match_count; $i++) {
            $e->setText(str_replace($variable, $value, $e->getText()));
        }
    } elseif (get_class($e) === $table_class && ($row_count = count($e->getRows()))) {
        foreach ($e->getRows() as $row) {
            foreach ($row->getCells() as $cell) {
                replaceText($cell->getElements(), $variable, $value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
$path = public_path('test.docx'); // Path to template document. public_path() Laravel function
$objReader = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createReader('Word2007'); // Here can be 'ODText' = .odt, 'Word2007' = .docx etc.
$docx = $objReader->load($path);
replaceText($docx->getSections(), '${text}', 'This will be in your document'); // '${text}' can be any text like 'Simple text'
$docx->save('test2.docx');
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a circular template from the template where I filled out the fields with the required $ {Value} values. I merged and saved the result as a new template. So it accepted the valuables

Comment: How does this improve previous answers ? Can you elaborate a bit on yoyr solution ?