# PhpWord doesn't replace text with TemplateProcessor

Tags: php, laravel, phpword, phpoffice

I encountered the same issue as @pindol in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794294/phpword-doesnt-replace-text).

I followed some steps provider by users in the page issue. So i tested functions in TemplateProcessor to see the outputs, and finally, the hole $TemplateProcessor with var_dump :

```
object(PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor)#1259 (9) { ["zipClass":protected]=> object(PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive)#1008 (5) { ["numFiles"]=> int(11) ["filename"]=> string(18) "/tmp/PhpWord5qX68E" ["tempDir":"PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive":private]=> string(4) "/tmp" ["zip":"PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive":private]=> object(PclZip)#1046 (5) { ["zipname"]=> string(18) "/tmp/PhpWord5qX68E" ["zip_fd"]=> int(0) ["error_code"]=> int(0) ["error_string"]=> string(0) "" ["magic_quotes_status"]=> int(-1) } ["usePclzip":"PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive":private]=> bool(true) } ["tempDocumentFilename":protected]=> string(18) "/tmp/PhpWord5qX68E" ["tempDocumentMainPart":protected]=> string(2690) " Test : the test is perfect" ["tempDocumentSettingsPart":protected]=> string(2842) " " ["tempDocumentHeaders":protected]=> array(0) { } ["tempDocumentFooters":protected]=> array(0) { } ["tempDocumentRelations":protected]=> array(1) { ["word/document.xml"]=> string(817) " " } ["tempDocumentContentTypes":protected]=> string(1312) " " ["tempDocumentNewImages":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

As we can see in ["tempDocumentMainPart":protected], the variable was replaced successfully with this function :

```
    $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('results/test.docx');
    $templateProcessor->setValue('test', 'the test is perfect'); 
    var_dump($templateProcessor);
    exit();
    $templateProcessor->saveAs('results/results.docx');
    return response()->download('results/results.docx');
```

But when i tried to saveAs or download the file, the variable doesn't change in the downloaded file. It's the same like the template provided and i got a error message when i try to open it (After download):

```
Word found unreadable content in results.docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If the source for this document is reliable, click Yes.
```

The function save and saveAs in the phpword :

```
    /**
 * Saves the result document.
 *
 * @throws \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\Exception
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function save()
{
    foreach ($this->tempDocumentHeaders as $index => $xml) {
        $this->savePartWithRels($this->getHeaderName($index), $xml);
    }

    $this->savePartWithRels($this->getMainPartName(), $this->tempDocumentMainPart);

    foreach ($this->tempDocumentFooters as $index => $xml) {
        $this->savePartWithRels($this->getFooterName($index), $xml);
    }

    $this->zipClass->addFromString($this->getDocumentContentTypesName(), $this->tempDocumentContentTypes);

    // Close zip file
    if (false === $this->zipClass->close()) {
        throw new Exception('Could not close zip file.'); // @codeCoverageIgnore
    }

    return $this->tempDocumentFilename;
}

/**
 * @param string $fileName
 * @param string $xml
 */
protected function savePartWithRels($fileName, $xml)
{
    $this->zipClass->addFromString($fileName, $xml);
    if (isset($this->tempDocumentRelations[$fileName])) {
        $relsFileName = $this->getRelationsName($fileName);
        $this->zipClass->addFromString($relsFileName, $this->tempDocumentRelations[$fileName]);
    }
}

/**
 * Saves the result document to the user defined file.
 *
 * @since 0.8.0
 *
 * @param string $fileName
 */
public function saveAs($fileName)
{
    $tempFileName = $this->save();

    if (file_exists($fileName)) {
        unlink($fileName);
    }

    /*
     * Note: we do not use `rename` function here, because it loses file ownership data on Windows platform.
     * As a result, user cannot open the file directly getting "Access denied" message.
     *
     * @see https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/532
     */
    copy($tempFileName, $fileName);
    unlink($tempFileName);
}
```

I tested this in the PhpWord 0.16.0 and 0.17.0 and i use this with laravel (i don't think that the issue is with laravel). Php version :

```
PHP 7.4.7 (cli) (built: Jun 12 2020 07:48:26) ( NTS )
```

I'm using PCLZIP instead of zipArchive because he generate a [memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512857/allowed-memory-size-problem-in-phpword-src-phpword-shared-ziparchive-php).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and managed to fix it !

I work on MacOS using the shipped version of Apache2, I don't know if you are still having this issue and in the same environnement as me, but I'm posting anyway in case someone else encounters the same issue.

## Steps :

#### 1. Download php@8.0

To download php@8.0, I ran the following commands ([source](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-upgrade-mac)):

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0
brew link --overwrite --force php@8.0
```

> Not php@8.1, this version (as of february 2022) causes DEPRECATED messages to show up [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1000)

#### 2. Update Apache2 configuration

And then I updated my `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file according to the brew installer message

(**always backup your config files before editing them!**)

```
To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
    LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

> I changed the LoadModule path to `/usr/local/opt/php@8.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so` as I had multiple versions of php downloaded

Then restarted Apache2 using :

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

#### 3. Use ZipArchive

Remove `Settings::setZipClass(Settings::PCLZIP);` and use ZipArchive.

> I can't assure that your problems using ZipArchive will disappear using php@8.0 as you seem to be having an other problem than I was, which was that ZipArchive was simply not found on my system.

## Conclusion :

My guess is that the issue comes with `Settings::setZipClass(Settings::PCLZIP)` unable to create normal OOXML (but only when using TemplateProcessor for some reason ? Because it worked perfectly when creating a new document with `new PhpWord()`)